# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. Find $ \mathbb P \{ \max(X, Y) - \min(X, Y) \gt 0.2 \} $.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables for which $X \sim
> > \text{exp}(2)$ and $Y \sim \text{exp}(3)$. Find $P(\max(X, Y) - \min(X, Y) \gt 0.2) $.

**1)** I know this answer has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687245/find-mathbb-p-maxx-y-minx-y-gt-0-2?rq=1), but I'm interested in the "clever way" suggested by the question poster. Does anyone know what he had in mind?

**2)** Also, regarding his own convolution method: He sets $T= \max(X, Y) - \min(X, Y)$ which means that $T=|X-Y|$ why does he need two integrals when he finds $F_T(t)$?

**3)** In the comments for that particular question, there is a guy who says that the second integral shouls start at $t$. Why does it start at $t$ in the second and on $0$ in the first integral?

Comment: i.i.d. means "independent and *identically* distributed".

Comment: Edited! thanks.

Comment: Consider the support of the distributions. That would make the appropriate limits of integration clear.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting property of exponential distributions is memoryless property. You can see exponential random variables as a model for arrival time of a thing. The memoryless property says that if you have waited until time $t_0$ and you have not observed any arrival, i.e. you know that $X> t_0$, then the arrival time still follows the same exponential distribution namely:
$$
P(X>t_0+s|X>t_0) = P(X>s).
$$

Now suppose that $Y$ is an arbitrary independent random variable, then you can still see that
$$
P(X>s+Y|X>Y)=P(X>s).
$$
Therefore for independent $X\sim\exp(a)$ and $Y\sim\exp(b)$, we have
$$
P(|X-Y|>s)=P(|X-Y|>s|X>Y)P(X>Y)+P(|X-Y|>s|Y\geq X)P(Y\geq X)\\
=P(X>Y)P(X>s)+P(Y\geq X)P(Y>s)\\
=P(X>Y)e^{-as}+P(Y\geq X)e^{-bs}.
$$
It remains to find $P(X>Y)$. See that:
$$
P(X>y|Y=y)=e^{-ay}\implies P(X>Y)=E(e^{-aY})=\int_{0}^\infty be^{-by}e^{-ay}\mathrm dy=\frac b{a+b},
$$
hence,

> $$
> P(|X-Y|>s)=\frac{a}{a+b}e^{-bs}+\frac b{a+b}e^{-as}.
> $$